# How to pass variable in array in a method?

Tags: php

I have very long multiple SQL queries that need to be used several times for different IDs. I think it's better to be put these queries in an array inside a method, so that I can call it anytime I want.

The problem is, I got stuck when trying to put the ID variable inside the queries. In a simple analogy, the codes are like this:

```
class SqlQueries {

  protected $_queries;

  private function $_queriesArr() {
    $_queries = array(
                  "SELECT * FROM tbl_a WHERE id = $id_a",
                  "UPDATE tbl_b SET b = NULL WHERE id = $id_b",
                  "UPDATE tbl_c SET c = NULL WHERE id = $id_c",
                );
    return $_queries;
  }

  public function $callQuery() {
    $id_a = 2;
    $tbl_a = $this->$_queriesArr();
    return $tbl_a[0];
  }

  public function $mainMethod() {
    echo $this->callQuery();
  }

}
```

I always get error with the variables inside the queries.

Comment: You may try with quotation around variable name. `SELECT * FROM tbl_a WHERE id = '$id_a'`.

Comment: change your array to something line array('queries'=>array(...),'variables'=>array()); or array(array('query'=>'...','vars'=>array(), array('query'=>'...','vars'=>array())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SqlQueries {

protected $_queries;

private function $_queriesArr($id_a='', $id_b='', $id_c='') {
$_queries = array(
              "SELECT * FROM tbl_a WHERE id = '".$id_a."' ",
              "UPDATE tbl_b SET b = NULL WHERE id = '".$id_b."' ",
              "UPDATE tbl_c SET c = NULL WHERE id = '".$id_c."' ",
            );
return $_queries;
}

public function $callQuery() {
   $id_a = 2;
   $tbl_a = $this->$_queriesArr($id_a);
   return $tbl_a[0];
}

public function $mainMethod() {
   echo $this->callQuery();
}

}
```

Comment: This one works. Thank you. I forgot to use concatenation. My bad day.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding some parameter like this, but why you naming your function start with $?
by the way, just add parameter to your function and hope it works just what you like

```
private function queriesArr($id_a, $id_b, $id_c) {
    $_queries = array(
                  "SELECT * FROM tbl_a WHERE id = $id_a",
                  "UPDATE tbl_b SET b = NULL WHERE id = $id_b",
                  "UPDATE tbl_c SET c = NULL WHERE id = $id_c",
                );
    return $_queries;
  }
```